# Force update cache when using OutputCache

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, outputcache

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms app with `OutputCache` set to xxx seconds. How can I invalidate cache when it is required to do? Specifically, I want to check if data in database is modified and if true, then force cache update. Is it possible and how to achieve that? So far I have added:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="24000" VaryByParam="myId" location="Server"%>
```

Now the problem is that `Page_init` is not fired with `OutputCache` and I dont know how to force cache update.

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://forums.asp.net/t/991603.aspx?+OutputCache+SqlDependency

Comment: @NoAlias Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var urlToRemove = Url.Action("AjaxHtmlOutputMethod", "Controller");
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(urlToRemove);
```